# CSS vertical-align: text-bottom;

Tags: css

Hi there I'm trying to position text to the bottom of the `<div>`. Neither `vertical-align:text-bottom;` or `vertical-align:bottom;`

The trouble is below it is my navigation buttons and if I push it down then they go out of alignment.

Is there a way I can work around this with my CSS?

```css
a:link {color:#452809}
a:hover {text-decoration:underline;color:#f00}
a:visited {color:#3886e0}
.fleft {float:left}
.fright {float:right}
.clear {clear:both}
* {border:0;margin:0}
**body {font:12px Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#666;background:#3cb40d}
#main {margin:0 auto;width:780px;background:#fff url(images/vitalbodyhealth.gif) no-repeat center top}
#header {width:780px;margin:10px; height:210px}
#logo {padding-right:10px;text-align:right;padding-bottom:9px;height:150px;vertical-align:text-bottom} 
#logo a {text-decoration:none;text-transform:lowercase;font-style:italic;font-size:16px;color:#fff;font-weight:bold}
#logo H2 a {font-size:10px}
#buttons {padding-top:0px;height:40px;width:780px}
#buttons li {display:inline}
#buttons a {display:block;float:left;width:80px;height:26px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;color:#fff;font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;padding-top:0px;margin-left:12px}
#buttons a:hover {width:80px;height:36px;text-decoration:underline}
#content {width:720px;margin:0 auto;padding:20px}**
.inner_copy {border:0;color:#f00;float:right;width:50%!important;margin:-100% 0 0 0;overflow:hidden;line-height:0;padding:0;font-size:11px}
#left {width:450px;padding:10px; background:#EFEFEF}
#left H1, #left H2 {color:#3cb40d;margin:0}
#left H1 {font-size:24px;padding:0}
#left H2 {font-size:18px;padding-top:10px}
#left a {color:#3886e0}
#left a:hover {text-decoration:none;color:#f00}
#left a:visited {color:#3886e0}
#right {float:right;width:240px; background:#EFEFEF}
#sidebar {width:240px;background:#EFEFEF}
#sidebar ul {margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none}
#sidebar li {margin-bottom:15px}
#sidebar li ul {padding:10px;border-top:none}
#sidebar li li {margin:0;padding:3px 0}
#sidebar li h2 {height:36px;margin:0;padding:10px 0 0 20px;background:#47872B;font-size:18px;color:#fff}
#sidebar a:link, #sidebar a:visited {text-decoration:none}
#sidebar a:hover {text-decoration:underline}
#sidebar li a {padding-left:10px;background:url(images/img09.gif) no-repeat 1px 5px}
#footer {background:#452809;height:47px;width:780px;margin:0 auto;font-size:10px;color:#fff;padding-top:23px;text-align:center;}
#footer div {padding:10px 38px}
#footer a {color:#fff;font-size:10px;text-decoration:none}
.padding {padding:10px;color:#f00;font-weight:bold}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

:)

Comment: Could we have html too? It might be helpful to diagnose the problem.

Comment: We need to see your HTML also. show as a live example, it will be much easier for us to help you. use for i.e. -jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 59):

### Modern solution

Flexbox was created for exactly these kind of problems:

```css
#container {
    height: 150px;/*Only for the demo.*/
    background-color:green;/*Only for the demo.*/
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <span>Text align to center bottom.</span>
</div>
```

### Old school solution

If you don't want to mess with table displays, then you can create a `<div>` inside a relatively positioned parent container, place it to the bottom with absolute positioning, then make it 100% wide, so you can `text-align` it to the center:

```css
#container {
    height: 150px;/*Only for the demo.*/
    background-color:green;/*Only for the demo.*/
    position: relative;
}

#text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <span id="text">Text align to center bottom.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The flex solution only works for me if height is added.

Answer (score 34):

To use `vertical-align` properly, you should do it on `table` tag. But there is a way to make other html tags to behave as a table by assigning them a css of `display:table` to your parent, and `display:table-cell` on your child. Then `vertical-align:bottom` will work on that child.

HTML:

```
​​​​​​<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        This text is vertically aligned to bottom.    
    </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS:

```
​.parent {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    display:​ table;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.child { 
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}​
```

Here is a live example: [link demo](http://jsbin.com/ozenoj/1/)

Comment: Thank you ever so much for the replies. This opens a real can of worms because the navigation buttons that should be below are moved to the top. I think the problem is that the banner has the green bar drawn onto it and so the navigation buttons fit nicely in place. Jees im a noob.

Comment: if it was on me, i would use jsut the `line-height` instead, it works also and it's simple then the way i suggested you.

Answer (score 7):

if your text doesn't spill over two rows then you can do `line-height: ;` in your CSS, the more line-height you give, the lower on the container it will hold.

Answer (score 4):

Vertical align only works in some select cases. The easiest way to make it function is to set `display: table` in the parent element's CSS and `display: table-cell;` to the child element and then apply your vertical align attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can play with padding and margin top, add line-height, etc.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gloak/7amYM/).

Style and text forked from @aspirinemaga

```
.parent
{
    width:300px;
    line-height:30px;
    border:1px solid red;
    padding-top:20px;
}
```