# Centering table in a div

Tags: html

This is what my code looks like:

```
<div id="outer">
   <div id="inner">
      <table> ... </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now, I need the table to be vertically aligned in the inner div. To do this, I added `display: table-cell;` and `vertical-align: middle;` to the inner div.

Now, the other thing I need is for the inner div to be horizontally aligned to the right inside the outer div. But as soon as I add `float: right;` to the inner div, the table is no longer vertically aligned inside it. I would mention that the outer div has a fixed width, while the inner div's width depends on the table.

Is there any way to bypass this problem?

Comment: http://theodorakis.net/tablecentertest.html

Comment: take a look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586171/css-vertical-align-text-bottom/13586293#13586293, i already answered this question. you should work on not only with inner element, but also with outer.

Answer (score 0):

try using `text-align: right` on `#outer` and please add some markup if it doesn't fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

If you you don't mind loosing the flow, you could try position `#inner` with `position:absolute`, as [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4pxHm/).

Answer (score 0):

try using this given below.

```
<div id="outer" align="center">
   <div id="inner" align="center">
      <table> ... </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

thanks

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using float to horizontaly align your table, just use the align property. Because float automatically put it on top and not the align property.

Comment: I have no idea what you just said.