# How to build some basic tiles with Title and Description?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I want to build some basic tiles using HTML/CSS, maybe utilize jQuery UI because I already use it for other things.

I am looking for something like this, and looking for HTML/direction on how to get it inside a web browser.

[image: mockup]

Namely, look at the HTML below.

Problems with HTML mark-up

- description does not float to the bottom
- adding subsequent square div boxes (aka "tiles") does not position them to the right of the previous box

```html
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:lightgrey;text-align:center">
  <div style="">Module</div>
  <div style="width:100px;height:20px;position:absolute">
    <span style=""> description </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want basic squares with text in them you probably want something like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .square {
                color:black;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 10px;
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="square">
            <h3>Module Name</h3>
            <p>Module is used for this and that</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you need to align the description to the bottom of the cell you could look at [CSS vertical-align: text-bottom;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586171/css-vertical-align-text-bottom)

For nicely aligning blocks that will appear to the right of each other and then wrap around into a grid, I recommend using lists with inline-block. A fiddle example is here. http://jsfiddle.net/89a07gm3/2

Comment: In order to get it 'inside a web browser' just copy that code into a .html file and then open that file with your web browser.

Comment: Yes, I want them to not stack but to have several tiles where each new tile appears to the right of the previous tile.

Comment: @Dennis float them in CSS: `.thing { float: left; }`

Comment: Or ` .thing {display: inline-block;} ` or some combination of that and float.

Answer (score 0):

My base result:

```css
.square {
  color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 50px 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="location.href='#';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="square">
  <h1>Module Name</h1>
  <p class="child">Module is used for this and that</p>
</div>
<div onclick="location.href='#';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="square">
  <h1>Module Name</h1>
  <p class="child">Module is used for this and that</p>
```

with credit to Beth + commenters