# How to vertically align a div to bottom of another div

Tags: html, css

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="nav">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <h1>name</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">About Me</a>
                    <a href="#projects" class="smoothScroll">Projects</a>
                    <a href="#skills" class="smoothScroll">Skills</a>
                </div>
            </div>
           </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="myBar">
            <img class="img-circle" src="images/pic.jpg"/>
            <i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

That is my HTML. I'm trying to align myBar to the bottom of the header. this is the css I've tried.

```
.nav{
position:relative;
}
.myBar {
position:relative;
vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

My image and icon just appear in a randoms spot towards the middle of the header.

Comment: There's a typo in the CSS..... `{` should be `}` ... does fixing that correct the issue?

Comment: I just copied that wrong onto here. My bad. It doesn't fix it though.

Comment: your code work fine : https://jsfiddle.net/myzs7mwm/

Comment: hah! if only `vertical-align` worked like that. Flexbox would help you with this. Please update your question to include a [mcve] ideally using the stack snippet tool in the editor.

Comment: I couldn't find the issue when I put this into JSfiddle.. but I researched a little and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586171/css-vertical-align-text-bottom) and then did the same with your code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1navbhz7/). Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Thanks for the help but it doesn't work. The damn thing just wont budge.